# SAML Exception Intended destination endpoint did not match

Tags: saml-2.0

A client is trying to SSO into our app using SAML and our app throws followimg exception

org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException: SAML message intended destination endpoint did not match recipient endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this exception was missing Destination attribute in the Response element in the the assertion client was sending us. The Response needed to be something like:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_a8590dae-831c-4142-9fc9-a15f60e972a0" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2012-02-22T17:08:57Z" Destination="https://client.ourapp.com/product/AssertionConsumer" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
```

The Destination attribute needed to contain our assertion consumer url.